# How do I track the amount of data sent/received on iOS?

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlsession

I'd like to track how much data is transferred to/from an iOS app's backend server. I'm using Apple's NSURLSessionDataTask, which automatically handles gzip decompression. I can easily get the size of the decompressed data. Is there any way to get the size of the data before decompression? Or even better, the size of all data transferred, not just the body?